# Google Webmaster Tools says my XML sitemap “appears to be an HTML page”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sitemap, google-search-console

I am submitting my dynamic sitemap for a rails app in "sitemap.xml.gz" format
but the google web master tool is not indexing it.

I am getting this error.

```
"Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead."
```

My website has videos and images. And i am creating sitemap using [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem.

This is the sitemap that is generated.

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:geo="http://www.google.com/geo/schemas/sitemap/1.0" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:pagemap="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-pagemap/1.0" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com/how-it-works</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com/features</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com/features/for-everyone</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com/features/for-brands</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://relatednoise.com/themes</loc>
<lastmod>2015-07-08T15:21:48+05:30</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sitemap seems to redirect to your homepage, and that's the HTML page.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 20:13:46 GMT
Location: https://relatednoise.com/
Server: nginx/1 [...]
```

Comment: Thanks @methode but i cant seem to figure out why its being redirected to home page.

Comment: It appears anything that doesn't exist will redirect to the homepage. Try to look in the server configuration files for clues.